# Prove the following inequality for non-negative Borel measurable functions defined on $\Bbb R.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

> Let $f : \Bbb R \longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a Borel measurable function. Show that $$\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \text {m} \left (\left \{f \gt n \right \} \right ) \leq \int f\ \text {dm} \leq \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \text {m} \left (\left \{f \geq n \right \} \right ) },$$ where $\text {m}$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Approximating $f$ by a non-negative sequence of increasing simple measurable functions I find that $$\begin{align*} \int f\ \text {dm} & = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left [\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n 2^n - 1} \dfrac {k} {2^n}\ \text {m} \left (\left \{\dfrac {k} {2^n} \leq f \lt \dfrac {k + 1} {2^n} \right \} \right ) + n\ \text {m} \left (\left \{f \geq n \right \} \right ) \right ]. \end{align*}$$

How do I proceed now? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Source** $:$ ISI (Indian Statistical Institute) PhD entrance test in Mathematics held in $20$th September this year, TEST CODE $:$ MTA (FORENOON SESSION), Question No. $7.$

Comment: If $0 \leq f <1$ the inequality fails.

Comment: You are making mess of things by omitting summation over $n$.

Comment: What does that prove? Does it prove what you are asked to prove?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes. For example, I don't see how it holds for $f=1/2$.

Comment: @mathmather for $f \equiv \frac {1} {2}$ we have $0$ everywhere. Isn't it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
\int f\,dm=\int_{0}^{\infty}m(\{f>x\})\,dx=\sum_{n\ge 0}\int_{n}^{n+1}m(\{f>x\})\,dx
$$
and
$$
m(\{f>n+1\})\le\int_{n}^{n+1}m(\{f>x\})\,dx\le m(\{f>n\}),
$$
one gets
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}m(\{f>n\})\le\int_{0}^{\infty}m(\{f>x\})\,dx\le \sum_{n\ge 0}m(\{f>n\}).
$$

Comment: I have checked your arguments for indicator functions. How do I extend it to non-negative simple measurable functions? To show those results for any non-negative measurable function we need to first approximate the function by an increasing sequence of simple measurable function and then apply monotone convergence theorem. But applying it how do I get the result?  You should add some more things to it so that it becomes accesible. May I know which book do you follow?

Comment: \begin{align}
\int f\, dm &=\int\left(\int_0^{\infty} 1\{f>x\}\, dx\right)dm \\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int 1\{f>x\}\, dm\right)dx \\
&=\int_0^{\infty} m(\{f>x\})\, dx
\end{align}

Comment: What is $1 \left \{f \gt x \right \}\ $? Do you mean $\chi_{\left \{f \gt x \right \}}\ $?

Comment: Are you claiming that $\displaystyle {f(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{\left \{f \gt x \right \}}(t)\ dx}\ $? I am having hard time to prove it (the equality) even for non-negative simple measurable functions. Can you please help me in this regard?

Comment: For a real number $z$,
$$
z=\int_0^z 1\, dx=\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[0,z]}(t)\,dx.
$$

Comment: Yeah! It's ok. Now what do you want to claim from here?

Comment: That's it. Replace $z$ with $f(t)$.

Comment: So we have $$f(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{[0,f(t)]} (s)\ dx.$$ But can you plaese make it clear to me $:$ how does it imply that $$f(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{\left \{f \gt x \right \}} (t)\ dx\ ?$$ Thanks.

Comment: So you have made a mistake in one of your above comments. You should have $$z = \int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{[0,z]} (x)\ dx.$$ Then everything is fine.

Comment: Indeed, it is a typo. Here is the correct result:
$$
z=\int_0^z 1\, dx=\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[0,z]}(x)\,dx=\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[0,z)}(x)\,dx.
$$

Comment: So we indeed have $$f(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{[0,f(t)]} (x)\ dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{\left \{f \gt x \right \}} (x)\ dx.$$

Comment: Can you also please elaborate the part that how do you get $$m(\{f>n+1\})\le\int_{n}^{n+1}m(\{f>x\})\,dx\le m(\{f>n\})\ ?$$

Comment: For $x\in [n, n+1]$, $\{f>n+1\}\subseteq \{f>x\}\subseteq \{f>n\}$.

Comment: Many many thanks for your help.